# Nonlinear Differential Equation with unknown source

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've encountered this equation:
$$S(t)-y(t)=\alpha \left(\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\right)^2$$
where $S(t)$ is a non-defined source (input of our system) and $\alpha$ is a positive constant.
I've tried variable separation but without any success.
Please, can someone help me find a solution or a possible approach?

Thanks

Comment: This is equation: $\alpha(y’)^2=S-y$?

Comment: Yes! I think that take the derivative of both sides by the variable $t$ produces something similar to the Abel differential equation... But I don't know how to proceed

Comment: I think that an Abel form is the best you can hope for. Without knowing more about the structure of $S$, it is hard to proceed in generality.